# ListActivity Custom BaseAdapter; duplicating list only when original list is re-ordered

Tags: java, android, duplicates, baseadapter, listactivity

I'm using a ListActivity with a custom BaseAdapter. The implemented `clear()` method clears the list only `onResume()`, but if I to repopulate the adapter and notify that the data has changed, it stays clear.

I don't believe any code is necessary, but...

```
ArrayList<String> thisWorks = DatabaseMethods.retrieveData();
populateAdapter();

---------------------------
ArrayList<String> thisAddsSameDataWithEveryIntentCall = sortByDate(DatabaseMethods.retrieveData());
populateAdapter();
```

My understanding is that it most likely has something to do with memory address changes. However, the data that SQLite gives me is NOT in order and must be re-ordered EVERY time because I want sequential dates.

I think that by sorting the data, it's using a different memory address every time, whereas resuming the activity, it's looking up old addresses.

Tips on preventing duplicates of data when calling an Activity?

---

### **EDIT**

The ArrayList thisWorks above will contain the following data:

- 01/09/2013
- 08/22/2012
- 07/26/2012

If I call this activity, these items populate CustomAdapter. When the activity is called, the Database function is called again (because the user may have added data), and in the event that it doesn't change, the same list is used to populate the CustomAdapter....all is well

The ArrayList thisAddsSameDataWithEveryIntentCall above will contain the following data **BEFORE SORTING**:

- 01/09/2013
- 08/22/2012
- 07/26/2012

After sorting:

- 07/26/2012
- 08/22/2012
- 01/09/2013

If I call this activity, these items populate CustomAdapter normally the first time. Hit the back button, remove Activity from stack. Click button to call Activity again:

- 07/26/2012
- 08/22/2012
- 01/09/2013
- 07/26/2012
- 08/22/2012
- 01/09/2013

Duplicates.

Something isn't being destroyed. I use a slightly modded version of a list after selecting a date choice, and because I do **NOT** sort the data this time, there is no data duplication.

Comment: doesn't making the ArrayList final work??

Comment: Added a more clear explanation. I was tired last night. Also, I'll give the **FINAL** a shot tonight, although based on what's happening, I don't think the ArrayList itself is the issue...or maybe it is. All tips are welcome.

Comment: Archie.bpgc, "final" worked fine, but if you added new data, then you'd have to wait until the Activity was destroyed or if the app was closed and opened again.

For some reason, the adapter saw that if the ListActivity contained the method to sort the ArrayList, then it would add onto the list. I moved to the source and sorted the ArrayList before the DatabaseMethod.selectAll() method returned its ArrayList. If the ListActivity receives ALREADY-SORTED data, then it behaves normally.